# Vertical rule within a div

Tags: css, html, alignment

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gfn9U/2/)

I have a "vertical rule" within a div (actually the `border-right` of a nested div). However, I am having trouble making it span the whole of its container. I have tried modifying the margins (try removing the comments from `margin-top: 20px;` in the `#vr` but to no avail.

Also, how do I make the `#wrapper` expand to fit its contents?

EDIT: Sorry, I was unclear. I am trying to work around the padding in the `#wrapper` because it's necessary for other things.

EDIT: [I've worked it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Gfn9U/5/): or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  Just make the outer div span its contents?  Why not just use Width: 100%? or something else equally as easy... unless I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm mainly trying to make the "vertical rule" touch the top and bottom edges of the wrapper. As a side note I asked how to make the wrapper expand vertically to fit its contents as this page will eventually be dynamic.

Comment: I can answer that question.  If you want the wrapper to dynamically resize, remove the `width` css value (or set it to `auto`. same effect). and then for spacing around it  use margin or make the width 90% or whatnot.

Comment: You either need to add 20px of padding to the top of `vr` or remove it from `wrapper`. A quick note, having both `padding:10px;` and `padding-top:20px;` on the `wrapper` is redundant. Instead just do `padding:20px 10px 10px 10px;`.

Comment: @Andrew Peacock That is incorrect. css cascades so setting `padding: 10px` and then `padding-top: 20px` results in `padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px`. I do it all the time for easier notation.

Comment: @Joseph You are correct, I'd forgotten about that! I just prefer having them all in one line personally.

Comment: @Sebastin. Aside from negative margins. You could use background image in the outer element. Or you could wrap the content on each side and use paddings in tehm separately without the need for padding in the surrounding element. I personally like background image solution in many occasions, but then again i got photoshop and know how to use it. Or depending a little, you could use position absolute

Answer (score 1):

the padding needs to be a property of #vr Does this look right? http://jsfiddle.net/Gfn9U/4/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the padding in the wrapper

Make the top and bottom paddings 0px

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - the padding in the wrapper is there for other things. Would it be possible to work around it?

Comment: @Sebastian Add `padding-top` to `vr` equal to the `padding-top` of `wrapper`.

Comment: There's not much of a cleaner way unless you make the height of the div over 100% or do what you already did. You'd have to put the padding on the inner div